# Qt Multithreading: ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: when sending signal from thread (QRunnable) to main thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

I am new to multithreading. It seems many people have a similar problem. I searched a lot for an answer. However, I cannot figure out why I get the following error in my case:

ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread. Current thread 26ff4538. Receiver '' (of type 'RuleSetVerifier') was created in thread 90b6c0", file kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp, line 553

From my main thread I start a QRunnable thread:

```
ConditionAnalysisManager* analysisManager = new ConditionAnalysisManager(param1, param2);
    connect(analysisManager, SIGNAL(conditionAnalysisResultReady(const QString&, int, bool, QMap<QString, bool>, const QString&)), this, SLOT(evaluateAnalysisResult(const QString&, int, bool, QMap<QString, bool>, const QString&))); 
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(analysisManager);
```

The result calculated in the thread are sent back to the main thread via a signal/slot connection.  In the ConditionAnaylsisManager  I do the following:

```
void ConditionAnalysisManager::run()
{
     this->analyzeConditions(param1, param2);
}

void ConditionAnalysisManager::analyzeConditions(int hostId, const QString& param2)
{
 //calculations
    emit conditionAnalysisResultReady(uid, hostId, finalResult,  ruleSetResults, finalDataString);
}
```

The Alert happens when the signal is emitted. I tried to implement it as described in
http://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects#Signals_and_slots_across_threads

As far as I understand it is possible to call a slot in the main thread from a thread. I tried with Qt::QueuedConnection and with default. I always get the Alert. Why?? What is wrong in my case?

In the constructor of the ConditionAnalysisManager class that inherits QRunnable I create an object of a helper class which does not inherit from QRunnable.

```
this->m_ruleSetVerifier = new RuleSetVerifier(param1, param2);
```

I mention this because the Alert says " Current thread 26ff4538. Receiver '' (of type 'RuleSetVerifier')". I cannot understand why the thread is of type RuleSetVerifier and not of type ConditionAnaylsisManager since the signal is emitted from the ConditionAnalysisManager. What is wrong??

I am looking forward to your help. Thank you!

Comment: And how do you use this `RuleSetVerifier` object?

Comment: I call methods in this class and return the results. There are no signal/slots in the RuleSetVerifier.

Comment: There is too much code missing to be able to find the source of the problem. You seem to be trying to do something with the `RuleSetVerifier` object from the wrong thread. You should know that it lives in the main thread, while everything you do in `ConditionAnalysisManager::run` is executed on the new thread.

Comment: Thanks! Why is the RuleSetVerifier object in the main thread when I create it in the ConditionAnalysisManager thread? It should be in the ConditionAnalysisManager thread. How can I get it there? Should I do moveToThread?

Comment: Because you create it in the constructor. The only part which runs in the new thread is what happens in the `run` method. So you have create it in the `run` method, and make sure you only use it the new thread. Or you can use the [worker object](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) design.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that every object I make in the new thread belongs to the new thread. I will try the worker object design, since the RuleSetVerifier has also a helper class and I want all this to be running in the new thread. I hope that this is possible.

Comment: In Qt, when you call [`moveToThread`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread), it moves all children to a new thread as well. Just make sure you set the parent to your child objects.

Comment: This question has way too little detail to figure out. Minimize your code. Throw out *everything* that's unnecessary to reproduce, then shove it all of it into a single `main.cpp` (like e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577062/1329652)). Then update the question to include the minimal `main.cpp`. You shouldn't need more than a 100 lines to show the problem. All I see at the moment is that it works for me if I fill in the blanks that you didn't provide. As it stands, the question is off-topic. If you ask about code, you *must provide it*.

Comment: I think my code is minimized. If you read the comments you will see that thuga (thanks a lot!) already pointed me to what I understood wrong. I am trying to fix it. This is a bit difficult since the project is pretty complex.